# How to use the functions for list filtering

Tags: vue.js

I am struggling to learn implementing api in vue and filter the data but I can’t make it work.

This is code sandbox I created:
https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-architecture-91tj6?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:943-971&codemirror=1

I am able to print the data but not to filter them even though I am using function for it.

If anyone can lead me in right path I would appreciate.

Comment: you are getting a list of objects from api. what field of those objects are you trying to filter the array on? Also, what is the purpose of `results` array in your data(), besides `filteredResults`?

Answer (score 1):

I saw your sandbox, here is how to make your code work:

```
  methods: {
    onChange() {
      axios
        .get("https://api.github.com/users")
        .then((response) => {
          this.results = response.data;
          this.filterResults();
          this.modal = true;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.errors = true;
        })
        .finally(() => console.log("Data successfully loaded"));
    },
    filterResults() {
      this.filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
        return result.login.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase());
      });
    },
    .............
```

Explanation:

In your code, you write:

```
onChange() {
  axios
    .get("https://api.github.com/users")
    .then((response) => {
      this.filteredResults = response.data;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.errors = true;
    })
    .finally(() => console.log("Data successfully loaded"));
  this.filterResults();
  this.modal = true;
},
```

You can see the position of `this.filterResults();` is wrong. That is because you put the method outside of `axios` or calling api. The `axios` is asynchronous function, it means that it will wait for the data to be loaded, while method `this.filterResults();` don't need to wait. This means that the method `this.filterResults();` will be loaded before the `axios` function finished even if you put it in the order below the `axios` function, basically it means that you are calling `this.filterResults();` function when the data is still empty. The solution to this is that by calling `this.filterResults();` inside the `axios` function, you can put it in `.then()` if you want to use the successfully retrieved data.

The second problem in your code is in the filtering logic.

```
filterResults() {
  this.filteredResults = this.results.filter((result) => {
    return result.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
  });
},
```

From what I understand, you want to filter the result with the `this.search` data from the input. Here you are calling `this.results`, but when do you assign any value to the `this.resuts`? in the `axios` you assign the value to `this.filteredResults = response.data;` instead of `this.results= response.data;`, it means the variable `this.results` is empty. So you have to change `this.filteredResults = response.data;` to `this.results = response.data;` in `axios`.

Next is the logic in your filter

```
return result.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1;
```

What you want to achieve is filtering the `result.login` with `this.search` value. But here you are filtering the `result` which as object type data with `this.search` value. Also, you don't need to put `> -1` operation, because `includes` will return `true` or `false`.